# Get Youtube Videos and Playlist IDs by Username with Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I want to get all uploaded Videos and Playlists from Youtube by Username and API Key. I don´t understand the Youtube documentation. I have only this Code. This Code returns the Videos from a Playlist

```
   <script>
        function onGoogleLoad() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('************************************');
            gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {

                var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.list({
                    part: 'snippet',
                   // playlistId: 'LL9eLmuGsghccGlo8D7pBu0Q'
                   // playlistId: 'PL625700BA4E23ECCC'
                    playlistId: 'UCPOmsF_XgQohcJhdj58zshg'

                });

                request.execute(function(response) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
                        console.log(response.items[i].snippet.title )
                        console.log(response.items[i].snippet)
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onGoogleLoad"></script>
```

How i can insert a Username from Youtube to get the data???